# Windows-7:Disable internet connection sharing on network adapter when it's in hidden state?

Tags: c#, networking, windows-7, registry

I'm trying to share internet over a network adapter on windows-7 using `NetConLib.dll`.

In order to do this, internet sharing should be *disabled* on all other network adapters.

In *normal* cases. I can iterate all the installed network adapters and disable sharing on them.
*However*, sometimes when the network device is *unplugged*, the adapter is ***hidden*** in windows.
But it's properties is still present inside windows registry.

I can't even find the adapter in Control Panel.
And off course, can't iterate it using the `NetConlib` library.

## Possible scenarios.

- The easiest way, would be using a windows command to disable internet
  sharing on all the adapters. Regardless of their visibility.

  *Is that possible in anyway ?*
- The second solution is to recover the network adapter from hidden state, so that
  `NetConlib` could iterate through it and disable it.

  *I tried to find the adapter's properties in windows registry and `unhide` it, But couldn't find anything*.

**Any solution?**

---

## @erm3nda.

Thank you for the informative answer. Although it didn't fix the problem I'm facing with `NetConlib`.

SC config correctly shuts down ICS service. But the shared network adapter continues on being *flagged* as `Shared`<sup>**1**</sup>. So ICS service being turned *off* doesn't seem to affect the adapters' settings.

Quite interestingly; when you try to share another adapter using windows GUI (`Right click on adapter -> Properties -> Share`), a message is prompted telling you

> "there is another adapter being shared currently, your new adapter
>   will be shared instead". You click ok and it's done.

I've been digging the entire internet the whole afternoon to see if there are other solutions using CMD commands.

Maybe there could be a away to share an adapter with a command. This way windows would handle disabling other adapters. In a similar way as when the GUI is used.

---

<sup>**1: Windows tells you which adapter is currently being shared in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`).**</sup>

Answer (score 6):

**Possible solution 1: Disable ICS at all.**
You can stop ICS service, so none of the connections will be at sharing status and will not conflict with `NetConLib.dll`. (Not sure about the hidden ones, you must try).

You can manage it from command line using:
        `net start SharedAccess` or `net stop SharedAccess`

Also, if you need to disable it from reboot to, must disable service using:
        `sc config SharedAccess start= disabled`

Notes and references:

- Executing `sc config` will display "start= OPTIONS" and some other.
  The space below = and option is mandatory. You can check result
  running `services.msc` from Run or cmd.
- Exec `net` to display OPTIONS. The name of service is on the
  services.msc list under "Name of the service" label from ICS service.
- netsh routing is not on Win7 anymore, so you only can
  start/stop/enable/disable but not enable for a particular Interface.
  You must set by handMouse... This not work under Win7 [ICS into XP
  system](http://forums.devshed.com/windows-help-34/enabling-ics-under-command-line-89499.html)
- `Sc Config` command was from [this cool documentation i found
  today](http://docs.oseems.com/general/operatingsystem/windows/firewall-command).

**Possible solution 2:** Remove ghost interfaces?
I try also around Adapters and interfaces into registry and do not see anything about show/hid/ghost/enabled or similar. I also search here [kb 314053](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314053/es) for registry conf.

I can suggeest try Possible solution 1 :) or directly delete hidden/ghost adapters.
You can do it by two ways. Devcon remove option will delete also drivers.

- Device manager: Run `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1` and run
  `devmgmt.msc`. You must see over "See" a "Show hidden" option. The
  show_nonpresent must reveal also hidden devices, not only inactive.
  [kb 269155 - You must click over #link named "Let me fix it
  myself"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269155#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways)
- With devcon.exe utility: This is a device manager tool from Windows
  with power moves.  [You will find a very big and helpfull guide
  here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ddk_example_36_remove_a_particular_network_device_tools).

Basic usage for find netcards `devcon findall =net`, also you can `devcon findall =net *ndis*` to list all ndis cards. 
Basic usage for remove will be `devcon remove =net *ndis*` to remove all ndis card type.

I try also enable/disable commands but nothing has change into my network interfaces list.
I removed my own wifi card to test it :) Anyway, i didn't notice any option about "Unhide" feature for such devices from conections panel.

**NEW EDIT (Too much verbose, right?)**

I found a tool called **ics-manager** [from this superuser post. - read answer #3](https://superuser.com/questions/470319/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line)
You can download directly from [utapyngo's Git project page](https://github.com/utapyngo/icsmanager).

It's based on .Net Framework 4. Yo must download and run the build.bat to compile both exe's (You got also the C# source). The solution is to get only the compiled IcsManager.exe (command line version) with the only needed library IcsManagerLibrary.dll.

**This app is using also `NETCONLib.dll`**, so you can use it, or read the source to see wich is the correct function you need to do it and implement on your development.

If you got problems with the Ip range "192.168.137.1", you can set from Registry permanently, or run `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="YOUR-INTERFACE" source=static addr=192.168.2.1 mask=255.255.255.0`. You will got ugly errors from launch the `netsh interface` using tilde or accutes into interfaces name (Spanish default ethernet name is "Conexión de áreal local"... a joke).

Note: You can pack all at once, using first a Bat to `call` the IcsManager.exe' with the arguments needed, then launch the netsh configure command later from same batch to full configure.

Comment: About the prompt when try to overwrite an shared connection, it's surely because only one could be shared. I also see, they are configured as Public and Home to set the pair, but i can't find where's the registry key...Also make some exports from reg and using Diffs, no lucky. I got stuck at diffs and start to search "ICS C++ and C#" on Google, then found it.

Extra: I got the `netsh` it into a bat, and [it's launched for Windows Task when a Ethernet cable is plugged (Here is the howto)](https://superuser.com/questions/583320/how-to-run-a-windows-application-when-the-ethernet-cable-is-connected) in order to use with Android Reverse Tethering. As you can see, im too interesting into your question because it makes me research better and also learned a lot.

Sorry about my bad English. Im not.
Regards.

Comment: +1, thanks a lot for the very advanced answer. Please see the I updated my post  :)

Comment: I edited answer with the unique working solution i found!
 
I search about 5 hours and try some C++/C# solutions to compile from diverse sites. None of them work and others was copycat power... not working. 

The cool documentation about the API is here msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/… but i dont know really to mucho into develop C/C++ nor C#.

Comment: Well, it doesnt work, but anyways, it was q good expirnce to know. Qll this docs and libraries. None of them worked, but you deserve the +200 for your efforts.

Comment: I will not tick it as an acceptedanswer, by the way, you seems to be an advanced user, hopefily see your real account someday :)

Comment: Did you run IcsManager.exe with Admin rights? I cannot believe it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, No, it's a strange exception happens, I will post another quetion about that, and comment you the link to new question as it's a different subject.

Comment: Still alive? tried to contact you from profile (just curious), but maybe i had to ask howto before haah.

Comment: And I can believe it does not work. It often does not. If it does not, feel free to open a new issue at GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I found that by going into Device Manager, you can show the Hidden Devices and try to disable the internet sharing on the adapters.

Hopefully this is near what you are asking. Good luck!

Atm

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 10 years late to the party, but the complete solution to this problem is nowhere else on the internet. In order to disable internet connection sharing for a device that is unplugged or uninstalled you will need to:

- Clear the shared access registry
- Clear the WMI sharing entry for the device
- Disable sharing through the netcon library

**Clearing the registry:**

You need to set two registry keys to `0xFFFFFFFF`:

- `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess\PrivateIndex` and
- `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess\PublicIndex`

For example in powershell:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess" -Name "PrivateIndex" -Value 0xFFFFFFFF
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess" -Name "PublicIndex" -Value 0xFFFFFFFF
```

**Clear the WMI sharing entry for the device:**

For every `HNet_ConnectionProperties` you must ensure `IsIcsPublic` and `IsIcsPrivate` is set to `false`. You can view which interface has `IsIcsPublic` or `IsIcsPrivate` set in powershell:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'HNet_ConnectionProperties' -Namespace 'root\Microsoft\HomeNet' | Format-Table
```

Unfortunately, the `Set-CimInstance` cmdlet does not appear to work in this scenario, so we have to choose another language. Fortunately, code to set these values to `false` can be found online. For example, here is some C# that performs this task (attibuted to [utapyngo](https://github.com/utapyngo/icsmanager))

```
    public static void CleanupWMISharingEntries()
    {
        var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\Microsoft\\HomeNet");
        scope.Connect();

        var options = new PutOptions();
        options.Type = PutType.UpdateOnly;

        var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM HNet_ConnectionProperties");
        var srchr = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        foreach (ManagementObject entry in srchr.Get())
        {
            if ((bool)entry["IsIcsPrivate"])
                entry["IsIcsPrivate"] = false;
            if ((bool)entry["IsIcsPublic"])
                entry["IsIcsPublic"] = false;
            entry.Put(options);
        }
    }
```

... and some vbscript (attributed to [billchaison](https://github.com/billchaison/Windows-Trix)):

```
set WMI = GetObject("WinMgmts:\root\Microsoft\HomeNet")
set objs1 = WMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM HNet_ConnectionProperties WHERE IsIcsPrivate = TRUE")
for each obj in objs1
    obj.IsIcsPrivate = FALSE
    obj.Put_
next
set objs2 = WMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM HNet_ConnectionProperties WHERE IsIcsPublic = TRUE")
for each obj in objs2
    obj.IsIcsPublic = FALSE
    obj.Put_
next
```

**Disable sharing through the netcon library:**

This part you probably already know, but for completeness, here is some powershell that does it:

```
regsvr32.exe /s hnetcfg.dll
$NetShare = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare

foreach ($RawConnection in $NetShare.EnumEveryConnection) {
    $Sharing = $NetShare.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.Invoke($RawConnection)
    $Sharing.DisableSharing()
}
```

The documentation for the relevant COM APIs for netcon can be found on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netcon/nn-netcon-inetsharingmanager)